# How to execute a string in a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, scripting, powershell-4.0

I have the following string

> "C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache{6b95042e-f763-4850-9136-d004dd0d0a9b}\AzInfoProtection.exe"
> /uninstall

I need to execute the above string as below

> First-line

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6b95042e-f763-4850-9136-d004dd0d0a9b}
```

> The second line (note there is no exe)

```
AzInfoProtection /uninstall
```

Variables are generally executed like below in PowerShell

```
Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

But how to split the above string into multiple lines for execution. Then I need to remove the quote and then exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand the ask here but I think I follow. Let me know if I'm off base or misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

```
$commandString = '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{6b95042e-f763-4850-9136-d004dd0d0a9b}\AzInfoProtection.exe" /uninstall'

# Get command parent directory
if( $commandString -match '^".*?"' ) {
  $runInDir = Split-Path -Parent $Matches[0]
}

# Change directories (use the location stack for easy traversal) 
Push-Location $runInDir

# Run program
Invoke-Expression $commandString

# Change back to previous directory
Pop-Location
```

This works by checking if the string starts with a quote-enclosed string (escaped quotes should not need to be handled within filepaths), and if so gets the first match from the `$Matches` object. `$Matches` is an automatic variable which is populated whenever you get a `$True` result using the `[-match operator][1]`. With the command path extracted, we use [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-5.1) to get the parent container relative to the filepath.

Then use [`Push-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location?view=powershell-5.1) to change directories. `Push-Location` works like `Set-Location` (aliased to `cd`) except it tracks the directories you leave and enter as a stack. Its sibling cmdlet [`Pop-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/pop-location?view=powershell-5.1) is used further on to return to the previous location.

Finally, we use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-5.1) to run your command. After this completes use `Pop-Location` to return to the previous directory. Keep the following in mind:

> You should take note that the use of `Invoke-Expression` is often implemented insecurely, and so you should consider heeding the warning on the documentation I've linked to and consider parameterizing your command if your `$commandString` is actually populated from a generated file, provided by a parameter, or another other outside source.

---

Note: You mentioned this in your question:

> The second line (note there is no exe)

Windows doesn't care if you omit the extension for executable types when executing them. You can run `AzInfoProtection.exe` with or without the `.exe` at the end. So unless I'm missing something this detail doesn't have any bearing on how this code works.

Answer (score 0):

To run the string you can pipe it to cmd to run it using:

```
$commandString | cmd
```